# How do I make this asp.net email go to a database?

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I ave a contact form (VS 2010 / VB / .net4), and when the client fills out the form, I get an email -- which I like, but ....

For instance, here's an e-mail I got:

> Email: ivy_league_alum-at-yahoo.com
>
> Subject: Do you guys integrate PPT?
>
> Message: I'm looking for a PPT integrator in the Michigan area.
>
> First_Name: Tim
>
> Last_Name: Dewar
>
> Organization: American Axle
>
> Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
>
> IP Address: 184.60.79.96
>
> Server Date & Time: 1/13/2012 11:28:59 AM

This is just a lead-generating company, so we're gonna get a lot of emails and we're gonna want them organized.

It was suggested by Jon P that I use a database to gather all these emails I'm getting, instead of MS Excel (which I wouldn't know how to do anyway).  So I downloaded SQL Server Express.  So now what do I do?  Can someone please tell me what I have to add to the code, specifically, or what I have to do, so I can gather these emails in an organized manner?  Thanks!

Addendum (I know this is long):

Specifically, my email code is:

> <%@ Page Title="Contact Health Nutts" Language="VB"
>   MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
>   CodeFile="contact.aspx.vb" Inherits="contact" %>   
>       
>           Protected Sub SubmitForm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
>               If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
>
> ```
>         Dim SendResultsTo As String = "jason.weber-at-healthynutts.com"
>         Dim smtpMailServer As String = "smtp.healthynutts.com"
>         Dim smtpUsername As String = "jason.weber-at-healthynutts.com"
>         Dim smtpPassword As String = "********"
>         Dim MailSubject As String = "Form Results"
>
>         Try
>             Dim txtQ As TextBox = Me.FormContent.FindControl("TextBoxQ")
>             If txtQ IsNot Nothing Then
>                 Dim ans As String = ViewState("hf1")
>                 If ans.ToLower <> txtQ.Text.ToLower Or ans.ToUpper <> txtQ.Text.ToUpper Then
>                     Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 3
>                     Exit Sub
>                 End If
>             End If
>
>             Dim FromEmail As String = SendResultsTo
>             Dim msgBody As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
>             Dim sendCC As Boolean = False
>
>
>             For Each c As Control In Me.FormContent.Controls
>                 Select Case c.GetType.ToString
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
>                         Dim txt As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower <> "textboxq" Then
>                             msgBody.Append(txt.ID & ": " & txt.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                         End If
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower = "email" Then
>                             FromEmail = txt.Text
>                         End If
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower = "subject" Then
>                             MailSubject = txt.Text
>                         End If
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox"
>                         Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(c, CheckBox)
>                         If chk.ID.ToLower = "checkboxcc" Then
>                             If chk.Checked Then sendCC = True
>                         Else
>                             msgBody.Append(chk.ID & ": " & chk.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                         End If
>
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"
>                         Dim rad As RadioButton = CType(c, RadioButton)
>                         msgBody.Append(rad.ID & ": " & rad.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"
>                         Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(c, DropDownList)
>                         msgBody.Append(ddl.ID & ": " & ddl.SelectedValue & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                 End Select
>             Next
>             msgBody.AppendLine()
>
>             msgBody.Append("Browser: " & Request.UserAgent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>             msgBody.Append("IP Address: " & Request.UserHostAddress & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>             msgBody.Append("Server Date & Time: " & DateTime.Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>
>             Dim myMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
>             myMessage.To.Add(SendResultsTo)
>             myMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail)
>             myMessage.Subject = MailSubject
>             myMessage.Body = msgBody.ToString
>             myMessage.IsBodyHtml = False
>             If sendCC Then myMessage.CC.Add(FromEmail)
>
>
>             Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword)
>             Dim MailObj As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpMailServer)
>             MailObj.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
>             MailObj.Send(myMessage)
>
>             Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 1
>         Catch
>             Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 2
>         End Try
>     End Sub
>
>     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
>         If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
>             Dim lbl As Label = Me.FormContent.FindControl("labelq")
>             If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
>                 Dim rq(3) As String
>                 rq(0) = "Is fire hot or cold?"
>                 rq(1) = "Is ice hot or cold?"
>                 rq(2) = "Is water wet or dry?"
>
>                 Dim ra(3) As String
>                 ra(0) = "hot"
>                 ra(1) = "cold"
>                 ra(2) = "wet"
>
>                 Dim rnd As New Random
>                 Dim rn As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 3)
>                 lbl.Text = rq(rn)
>                 ViewState("hf1") = ra(rn)
>             End If
>         End If
>     End Sub
> </script> </asp:Content> <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server"> <h1>CONTACT HEALTH
> ```
>
> NUTTS AND WORK FROM THE COMFORT OF YOUR OWN HOME!
>           
>               
>                           
>                       Enter your Email Address:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   * Please enter a valid email address.
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Subject:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Please type your message below:
>                       * Required
>                       
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       First Name:
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Last Name:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Phone Number:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   * Please enter a valid U.S. phone number (including dashes).
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       City:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       State/Province:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>               
>               
>                   Your message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us.
>               
>               
>                   Due to technical difficulty, your message may NOT have been sent.
>               
>               
>                   You did not correctly answer the anti-spam question. Please go back and try again.

Comment: Can you insert the form data directly in database instead of parsing the email content and getting the values, if yes your solution is straight forward

Comment: Ravi:  I haven't tried anything, since I'm not a programmer.  All I did was use a form I got online that goes along with VS 2010 .net4 ...  but I haven't tried anything.  I'm afraid that my web host might charge me for an SQL database.  I'm just confused.

Comment: Kronass, I'm not sure what you're talking about ... I wouldn't know.  I can post the code for the email form in here, but probably nobody would pay attn, since it's too long.

Comment: @Ravi please stop posting that. It's getting tiresome.

Comment: @JasonWeber In your contact form prior to sending the email you should be able to send those values to the database; so that you don't need to go through the hassle of parsing the email and doing the same afterwords.

Comment: the form you are using did you create it or you used an auto generate tool, do you have a direct access to the form code so you can manipulate it and add your code or not possible

Comment: Kronass, I used an auto generated tool -- specificallly, I used http://www.ctrfx.com/form/

Comment: can you use SQL server in your hosting but I prefer to use MS Access in your case , depending on your answer I will send you the code

Comment: Kronass, did you see my addition to the question?  I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Just remove the details from these lines (better safe than sorry)
    Dim SendResultsTo As String = "*********"
    Dim smtpMailServer As String = "***********"
    Dim smtpUsername As String = "************"

Comment: Oh, you mean as far as hackers up to deviant things?  I don't care about that, Hippo.  I'm more concerned about how to gather these emails and put them in some type of organized format.  But thank you!

Comment: I recommend you to use MS access because if you want to view the data all what you need to do is download the file and open it, no technical skills required and also it is free of charge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't take this the wrong way, but judging by what you've said about your lack of coding abilities, it may work out cheaper for you to get someone else to do the work for you. A competent coder should be able to knock something out for you in about an hour, probably less if he doesn't stop for coffee.

If you do really really want to do it yourself, then first off, you're going to have to find out if the hosting packing for the website includes a database or not.

Assuming you don't host the website on your local machine, then having a version of SQL Express on your machine will help you develop the code, but you won't be able to deploy it.

Completely ignoring that though, steps you want to go through are:

1. Create the database in SQL, then create the relevant database
   table
2. Create a connection from the website to the database using ADO.Net
3. Create the code to insert the contact form data into the database table

You then need to think about how you're going to view the data once it's been collected, so you're either going to have to write something or learn SQL.

If you want some code samples to help you get going, then we need to know what language you're using (it should be C# or VB.Net) and posting the code for the contact form would help as well (obviously deleting any sensitive details, such as usernames and passwords).

**EDIT:**

Once you've created the database, this script should give you a basic table structure in SQL Express:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmails](
    [EmailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEmails2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

To use it, right click on the database in SQL Express, click New Query, paste the above into the window, then hit the Execute button, refresh the database and you shouldn't see the table.

Comment: Oh, I'm definitely lacking coding abilities, Hippo.  I'm a robotics engineer.  But this is a start-up company and we don't have the money to hire a programmer -- but I doubt it'd be that cheap.   I use discountasp.net as my web host .... they allow 1 SQL database for 10 bucks a month ... but thank you for taking the time to read my issue, and respond. Thank you very much for laying out the steps I'd have to take, recognizing I'm not too adept at programming.  I do appreciate your help!

Comment: I tend to agree with @Kronass that an MS Access database may be better for you, but it depends on whether your hosting provider will allow you to have one or not.

Comment: Yes, they allow for an MS Access DB.

Comment: In that case, as much as I hate it, I'd use Access (which means you can probably ignore the script above :) )

Comment: Wow ... okay, thank you Hippo .... I really do appreciate you taking the time to help, and educate.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I've having a slow day :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial if you're using ajax too.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Developing-an-AJAX-and-ASP-NET-4-0-Based-Online-E-mail-System-Part1.aspx

Comment: Thank you Coder -- once again.  The email for is on http://www.healthynutts.com/contact.aspx ... I don't know much about the coding.  I got it online.  Changing it to Ajax would be really confusing for me ... But thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and respond to it.

Comment: you're welcome.Hope something gives you a start rather than giving up.